# Mysql annotate table with aggregated sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, which go like

```
t1
alias_id (string, unique)
finished (datetime)
sum (float)

t2
alias_id (string)
sum (float)
```

tables contain payments, around 800 k records each. t1 contains each payment just one time, while t2 can have several records with same alias_id - for some payments can consist of several transactions.

I need to compare the sum field in t1 to Sum of sum fields in t2, grouped by alias.

Doing it in Excel works, but is painful and takes about 4 hours. I tried uploading tables to mysql and running a query on them, was surprised to see it took like 8 hours to complete.

I have no idea why, maybe my query is bad? Or maybe grouping by time and sum does that? Could really use a general advice on best approach to the task.

Query goes below.

```
SELECT 
    s.alias_id AS id, 
    s.finished AS finished, 
    s.sum AS sum, 
    Sum(b.sum_aggr) AS b_sum 
FROM report.rep1 s 
LEFT  JOIN 
(    SELECT alias_id, SUM(sum) AS sum_aggr    
    FROM   report.rep2
    GROUP  BY 1    
) b 
ON b.alias_id = s.alias_id 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Table DDLs:

first:

```
CREATE TABLE `rep1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `corp_client_id` longtext,
  `agr_name` longtext,
  `client_id` longtext,
  `order_id` longtext,
  `alias_id` longtext,
  `due` longtext,
  `finished` longtext,
  `sum` double NOT NULL,
  `currency` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=720886 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

second:

```
CREATE TABLE `rep2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` longtext,
  `contract` longtext,
  `contract_start_dt` longtext,
  `contract_end_dt` longtext,
  `country` longtext,
  `provider` longtext,
  `date` longtext,
  `alias_id` longtext,
  `transaction_id` longtext,
  `payment_transaction` longtext,
  `transaction_type` longtext,
  `sum` double NOT NULL,
  `transaction_type_name` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=655351 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Assuming `rep1` translates to `t1` and analog for `2`. Why do you group by `t1.alias_id` in the outer query? You said this was unique so the `GROUP BY` of the outer query is like not grouping at all.

Comment: @stickybit well I guess you are right. I sort of assumed I need grouping for all fields if I'm using aggregation for some reason. Sorry, my sql is bleak :)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yup, launched it. I just wanted to see how long it takes before answering, thank you.

Comment: @Vémundr what are the indexing details on the two tables ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya alias_id look like '1df9f53a059e471b831169918c147bd6' if that is what you are asking about.

Comment: Stop using `GROUP BY 1, 2 , 3` it is to error prone.. Besides it's not ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Vémundr no I mean have you [Indexed](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-create-index/) the tables ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya oh, that. I did, just an int. I'm posting MySQL DDLs in the question.

Comment: @Vémundr please index `alias_id` as well on both the tables and set a foreign key relationship between them. Otherwise any query using `alias_id` will be slow no matter what.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya could you give an example of how to do that, with tables loaded with data already? I'm afraid I never did that before.

Comment: @Vémundr check the updated answer please. I have given alter table statements to add indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare that the Sums are matching, you can simply do a `left join` between the tables on `alias_id`. Now, just compute the `SUM` on the second table, and then you can compare them.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
    s.alias_id AS id, 
    s.finished AS finished, 
    s.sum AS sum, 
    SUM(b.sum) AS b_sum 
FROM report.rep1 AS s 
LEFT  JOIN report.rep2 AS s2 ON s2.alias_id = s.alias_id 
GROUP BY s.alias_id, s.finished, s.sum
```

**EDIT:** As observed by [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612932/mysql-annotate-table-with-aggregated-sum?noredirect=1#comment92161536_52612932), that `alias_id` is not indexed on either of the tables. Since the `alias_id` field is longtext type; it will need proper Indexing, otherwise queries will be slow no matter what. Now,  fields with `longtext` datatype cannot be indexed; so you will need to first convert them into `varchar` datatype.

```
ALTER TABLE `rep1` MODIFY COLUMN `alias_id` VARCHAR(255);
ALTER TABLE `rep2` MODIFY COLUMN `alias_id` VARCHAR(255);
```

You can add the indexing on both the tables as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `rep1` ADD INDEX alias_id (`alias_id`);
ALTER TABLE `rep2` ADD INDEX alias_id (`alias_id`);
```

If `alias_id` is going to be Unique in the table `rep1`, you can use the following statement (instead of the first statement above):

```
ALTER TABLE `rep1` ADD UNIQUE alias_id (`alias_id`);
```

Comment: Trying that. I also had to ALTER TABLE rep1 MODIFY alias_id VARCHAR(255); for longtext does not look to support indexing. Launched main query, waiting...

Comment: well, it worked. In less than 3 minutes. Thank you so much, tomorrow a bunch of people will be quite happy, all thanks to you :)

Comment: @Vémundr happy to help :)